# Bot does not print message when typing word in Discord chat. Node.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create a bot on discord that writes pong if I type a message in the "ping" chat.
For some reason it's not working.

```
require('dotenv').config(); //initialize dotenv
const Discord = require('discord.js'); //import discord.js

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
  ]}) //create new client

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});


client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
  });

//make sure this line is the last line
client.login(`TOKEN`); //login bot using token
```

Answer (score 1):

The Event is called messageCreate, that is the only wrong part in the coding. I still would recommand to import the Client etc directly and not just only Discord.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const {Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits}= require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ]})

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on(Events.MessageCreate, msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply('Pong!');
    }
  });

client.login(`TOKEN`);
```

Comment: This code won't work, you forgot to include the `MessageContent` intent in your intents array. For OP, also make sure to enable the `MessageContent` intent for your bot at the [Developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)